# Using format property of kendo-grid-column in ng-template?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

`kendo-grid-column` has a great column property 'format'. And [it works perfectly.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/)

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
    <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:n0}">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate format="{0:n0}" let-dataItem>
            <a href="#" class="badge badge-info">{{ dataItem?.UnitPrice }}</a>      
        </ng-template>
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:n0}">         
     </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

What I need is to add anchor tag and use `format` property of `kendo-grid-column`. So I've added `ng-template` to `kendo-grid-column`:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:n0}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate format="{0:n0}" let-dataItem>
        <a href="#" class="badge badge-info">{{ dataItem?.UnitPrice }} </a>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

However, `format="{0:n0}` is not working in `ng-template`:

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate format="{0:n0} let-dataItem>
    <a href="#" class="badge badge-info">{{ dataItem?.UnitPrice }} </a>
</ng-template>
```

I've created [an example to show what I have](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tftp1d?file=app/app.component.ts).

Is it possible to use `format` property of `kendo-grid-column` in `ng-template`?

Comment: You mean that it is set to `n0`(no decimal places) and the value is being displayed with two decimals places, right ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yeah, you are absolutely right!

Comment: Did you try to call the format function explicitly? see [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting#number-formatting)

Comment: @ps0604 yeah, I used these Kendo built-in methods to format numbers. Could you write your reply and I’ll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Kendo number formatting functions, such as

```
kendo.toString(10.12, "n5"); //10.12000
```

OR just use methods of [Kendo IntlService](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/api/IntlService/):

- formatNumber()
- parseNumber()
- format()

Answer (score 1):

Use an [internationalization pipe](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/pipes/).  I found the answer [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1754).

```
<kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:n0}">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate format="{0:n0}" let-dataItem>
        <a href="#" class="badge badge-info">{{ dataItem?.UnitPrice | kendoNumber: 'n0' }} </a>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```